# outputting contents of javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to replace the date in "events" below, with a list of dates that are returned from a JSON call, which are store in "bookedDates". Can anyone assist?

I will need to keep the : {} on each of the dates too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

var currentDate = yyyy + '-' + mm;

var bookedDates = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Ajax/getBooked",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            bookedDates = bookedDates.concat(response),
            bookedDates.toString;
        }
    });
    $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
        time: currentDate,
        events: {
            "2015-06-30": {}
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: We have no idea what `bookedDates` looks like ?

Comment: Apologies. It returns this: ["2015-06-15","2015-06-16","2015-06-17","2015-06-20","2015-06-22","2015-06-23"]

Comment: What is this expression supposed to do: `bookedDates.toString;`?

Comment: I need to replace the "2015-06-30": {} under events, with all of the dates returned via json.

Comment: The problem here is "giving new data to the responsiveCalendar program" — and we don't have the code for that.

Comment: Use the `edit` method to update the events: http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/#methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
events = {};

for (i = 0; i < bookedDates.length; i++) {
     events[bookedDates[i]] = {};
}
```

Demo plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/jz6cqrFN92DOrAekFfC8?p=preview,
go to the console to see the events object

Comment: This has worked i think :) thanks so much for your help. I've been searching the web for HOURS to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need loop through the array that is returned and create an object with each key being a date that is in the `response.responseJSON` object.

The `.responsiveCalendar({` function needs to be called within `success` callback so you can use the data that is returned from the AJAX call.

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

var currentDate = yyyy + '-' + mm;

//commented unless you are using this data in another part of the program
//var bookedDates = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Ajax/getBooked",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            //commented unless you are using this data in another part of the program
            //bookedDates = bookedDates.concat(response),
            //bookedDates.toString;

            //Assuming response.responseJSON = ["2015-06-15","2015-06-16","2015-06-17","2015-06-20","2015-06-22","2015-06-23"]
            var events = {};
            response.responseJSON.forEach(function (date) {
                events[date] = {}
            });

            $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
                time: currentDate,
                events: events
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If the calendar has already been loaded, the dates can be edited with the `edit` method: http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/#methods

Comment: Thanks jwatts, i will look through that link, and see if i can get the edit method working.

Comment: This piece of code doesn't seem to be working AnotherDev?            response.responseJSON.forEach(function (date) {
                events[date] = {}
            });

Comment: what is `console.log(response.responseText)`